# Instancing Static Meshes with Python

Tags: instances

Forgive me, I am relatively new to Blender and I am struggling with terminology shared with other 3D applications.

I am used to the term "instancing" being used to describe a situation where the geometry, UV mapping, materials etc of single static mesh are reused by perhaps 10s or 100s of thousands of shallow copies that only differ from the original static mesh in the transform.

The critical point is that there is only one draw call to the graphics card for all of these instances.

There are many examples where this is useful, for example: procedurally generating a forest. I would hope that when this is used, I would only see one object, on the scene graph, as a "container" for all the shallow copies. Hence, one click to hide or remove all the shallow copies. I am struggling to find any any explanations or useful examples. I suspect I am using the wrong terminology. I would be very grateful for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: Blender uses instancing automatically  when you clone an object with `Alt`+ `D` reaping the benefits of reduced draw calls and storage, but they will always remain independent objects in the *Outliner*. If you want them all together you may be looking for instancing through particle systems

Comment: Thank-you. I was being thrown by the linked duplicates appearing separately in the Outliner (scene graph). I come from paradigms where the instanced meshes "hide" behind one containing object. I might be able to achieve something similar with collections. Thanks again.